# How to drop columns if a row in a column has a "url"or "http" in it without knowing the column name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

How can drop column A because it has the following "https://" in python?

Back story: I have a 500 column Data Frame where 250 columns are "https://" links in the rows explaining what the prior variable is.

The goal is to loop through the df to drop columns that have "http://"

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| https://mywebsite | 25 |
| https://mywebsite | 42 |

My desired output is:

| B |
| --- |
| 25 |
| 42 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet should work, removing **any columns** that contain urls:

```
to_drop = []
for column in df:
  try:
      has_url = df[column].str.startswith('https://').any()
  except AttributeError:
      pass  # dtype is not string
  
  if has_url:
      to_drop.append(column)

df.drop(columns=to_drop, inplace=True)
```

For each column, it checks whether each row starts with 'https://'. If any of them do, then they are added to a 'to_drop' list of columns to drop. Then the columns in this list are dropped inplace.

The version below will only drop a column if **at least 50% of the values** in it are URLs:

```
to_drop = []
for column in df:
  try:
      has_url = df[column].str.startswith('https://').mean() > 0.5
  except AttributeError:
      pass  # dtype is not string
  
  if has_url:
      to_drop.append(column)

df.drop(columns=to_drop, inplace=True)
```

You can change **0.5** to another number between **0** and **1** to change how big of a percentage should be URLs in order for the column to be dropped.

Comment: I think the only issue that I am having is that I need to first convert all columns with "https://" from object to string, because it is detecting "none" columns.